# Why do we derivate to find the unit vectors in a new coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems

If I have a vector $\mathbf{u}=(x,y)$ in cartesian coordinates in a base with unit vectors $ \mathbf{\hat{i}}$ and $ \mathbf{\hat{j}}$, and want to find the unit vectors in a different coordinate system, say, polar coordinates, I know I can do so knowing that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and taking the derivatives of $\mathbf{u}$ with respect to $r$ and $\theta$. I was reading this page: http://www.physics.purdue.edu/~jones105/phys310/coordinates.pdf , where they say that " If a vector $\mathbf{r}$ depends on a parameter $u$, then a vector that points in the “direction” of
increasing $u$ is defined by $∂\mathbf{r}/∂u$ ".

In this thread [Spherical Coordinates and Unit Vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286713/spherical-coordinates-and-unit-vectors) I also found a similar explanation, that by derivating we find the direction in which the new parameter increases, but I still can't quite "visualize" why we have to take the derivatives with relation to the new parameters...

Comment: You can get the right font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and answer the question this way. We first discuss what a "unit vector"  really is and what it represents. This choice of *how to think about unit vectors* should directly lead us to the idea that the correct unit vectors are those defined by taking the derivative along those directions.

I first claim that "unit vectors" do not exist in general. Rather, we have "unit vectors at each point of the plane". What these unit vectors do is to tell us *in what directions the coordinates increase*.

I'd like to focus on the 2D case, where we have access to three coordinate systems, one being the standard cartesian coordinate system, one being polar, and the other being a weird coordinate system that I'm going to define, which is "different enough" to get the point across.

Let's say our space is $M = \mathbb R^2$. Now, by a *coordinate system*, I mean a function  $(c: M \rightarrow \mathbb R^2)$ such that $c$ is differentiable and is a bijection between $M$ and $\mathbb R^2$.  Note that I'm referring to our space explicity as $M$ and *not* as $\mathbb R^2$, since I *want* us to think of 2D space as a "collection of points", and not as numbers.

We have the usual cartesian coordinate system:

$$
E: M \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \qquad C(x, y) \equiv (x, y) \\
C_1(x, y) = x \qquad C_2(x, y) = y
$$.

If we now compute the gradient of $C_1$ (the direction along which $C_1$ increases),
we get:

$$
\nabla C_1
\equiv  \left( \frac{\partial C_1}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial C_2}{\partial y} \right)
= ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}) = (1, 0)
$$

which is indeed the usual unit vector, we denote by $\hat x$.
A similar computation will show us that $\nabla C_2 = (0, 1) = \hat y$.

So, I'm going to claim that this is the right way to think of unit vectors:
as **directions along which the coordinate increases**.

### An "exotic" coordinate system on $\mathbb R^2$

$$
E: M \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \qquad E(x, y) = (x-y, x+y) \\
E_1(x, y) = x-y \qquad E_2(x, y) = x + y
$$

We can get the sense of what a coordinate system is doing by plotting the lines of constant coordinate. So, I'm going to plot $E_1(x, y) = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, and similarly $E_2(x, y) = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$:

[image]

The red lines are equations of the form $x + y = 1$, $x + y = 2$, etc.
While the blue lines are equations of the form $x - y = 1$, $x - y = 2$, etc.

If we compute the gradient of $E_1$, this will give us the $E_1$ unit vector
that points in the direction of increase of $E_1$:
$$
\nabla  E_1 
\equiv \left( \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial y} \right)
= \left( \frac{\partial x-y}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial x-y}{\partial y} \right) 
= (1, -1) = \hat E_1           
$$

We can similarly compute $E_2$ to recieve $\hat E_2 = (1, 1)$. Notice that $\hat E_1$, $\hat E_2$
are perpendicular, just as $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are perpendicular.

### Polar coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$

We can go on to do the same thing, to find the gradients of the polar coordinates:

$$
P: M \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \qquad P (x, y) \equiv \left(\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}, \tan^{-1} y/x \right) \\
P_1(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \qquad P_2(x, y) \equiv \tan^{-1}(y/x)
$$

I leave computing $\nabla P_1, \nabla P_2$ as an exercise.

I hope this intuitively motivates why the gradient is our unit vector.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I understand it now.

Comment: one final question, in the case of polar coordinates for example, why do I get the same result if I derivate the position vector $\mathbf{u} = r\cos\theta \mathbf{\hat{i}} + r\sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{j}}$ with respect to $r$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

In the cartesian plane it is clear that a segment in the $x$ direction is orthogonal to one in the $y$ direction whatever is their length
and wherever they are located in the plane. 
They will remain orthogonal also in respect to a rotated cartesian reference system, since both are Euclidean and so maintain the 
dot product value of two given vectors. That is, the two systems are related through a ortho-normal transformation matrix.

Also the polar reference system is orthogonal to the Cartesian one, but the angle between the two is **changing** at varying
of $(x,y)$ or of $\phi$. The orthogonality  is preserved only at small scale, between $(dx,dy)$ and $(dr, r d\phi)$.
Two large straight segments in $(x,y)$ would become "distorted" in $(r, \phi)$ and the vectors corresponding to their endpoints 
will loose the preservation of the dot product.